# inserting values into mysql using php self-defined functions

Tags: php

I would like to insert values into a MySQL database but the values are not inserting and I don't know whats wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<?php


include("inc/connection.php");

function RegisterStep1() {

        $txtuser = $_POST['txtName'];
        $txtsurname = $_POST['txtSurname'];
        $txtemail = $_POST['txtEmail'];
        $txtpass = $_POST['txtPassword'];
        $txtconfirmpass = $_POST['txtConfirmPass'];
        $txtcontactperson = $_POST['txtcompanycontactname'];
        $txtCompAddress = $_POST['txtCompAddress'];
        $txtRegNo = $_POST['txtRegNo'];
        $txtuserpos = $_POST['txtuserpos'];
        $txtdepartment = $_POST['txtdepartment'];
        $txtcontacts = $_POST['txtcontacts'];
        /* check if values are posted */



        $txtuser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtName']);
        /* combo company type */
        $txtCompAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtCompAddress']);
        /* combo locations
         */
        $txtRegNo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtRegNo']);
        /* combo companysize */
        $txtcontactperson = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtcompanycontactname']);
        $txtsurname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtSurname']);
        $txtuserpos = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtuserpos']);

        $txtdepartment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtdepartment']);
        $txtcontacts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtcontacts']);
        $txtemail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtEmail']);
        $txtpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtPassword']);
        $txtconfirmpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtConfirmPass']);



        $q = "INSERT INTO company(Name,Type,Address,Location,RegisteredNumber,CompanySize,ContactPerson,Surname,Position,Department,Contacts,DateResgistered,AccountStatus,Email,Password)
      Values('" . $txtuser . "','" . $txtCompAddress . "','" . $txtRegNo . "','" . $txtcontactperson . "','" . $txtsurname . "','" . $txtuserpos . "','" . $txtRegNo . "','" . $txtdepartment . "','" . $txtcontacts . "','" . $txtemail . "','" . $txtpass . "')";

        $submitquery = mysql_query($q);
        if ($submitquery) {
            echo"<div id='results'>Error occured while creating account,please try again in few minutes</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div id='results'>Thanks for signing up</div>";
        }

}

?>
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting? Is it getting to Error condition at end?

Comment: Use `echo mysql_error()` to figure out what errors you got.

Comment: Post less code. Reduce your code to the smallest sample that still produces the error and post what's left. You'll probably find the problem yourself in the mean time. This is **debugging**, and you're expected to try it yourself before asking Stack Overflow to do it for you.

Comment: The output is Error occured while creating account,please try again in few minutes.and i have been trying to trace it but yet i'm not getting any glue.let me try mysql_error() to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: what is output of `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 1):

One funny thing, please check your condition

```
$submitquery = mysql_query($q);
        if ($submitquery) {
            echo"<div id='results'>Error occured while creating account,please try again in few minutes</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div id='results'>Thanks for signing up</div>";
        }
```

It should be

```
$submitquery = mysql_query($q);
            if (!$submitquery) {
                echo"<div id='results'>Error occured while creating account,please try again in few minutes</div>";
            } else {
                echo "<div id='results'>Thanks for signing up</div>";
            }
```

I think your code is working fine. :)

Comment: +1 and [*facepalm*](http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/3657230_700b.jpg)

Comment: deceze thanks for mysql_error() the problem was with the query itself but i ddnt know what to use to debug it.its working just fine now thanks :).Thanks to everyone.I'll post again if i run into any problem